# Eval command in unix

Tags: shell, shell-script

Can someone convert this code? I got this from the web.

Originally, there is a parameter from a command that is either a plus (+) sign
or a minus (-) sign. But since I only need now the addition (its not in the
parameter anymore), I want this to do addition automatically.

```
-|+) eval '(('jd2=${jd1}${5}${6}'))'
jd2date $jd2
```

Comment: Convert it to what? Could you give us an example input and desired output? What shell are you using? What operating system? What's jd2date? What is in `$jd2`?

Answer (score 1):

Does the code look like this?

```
case "$5" in
    -|+) eval '(('jd2=${jd1}${5}${6}'))' jd2date $jd2 
esac
```

If so, you might call the command like so:

```
script arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 + 6
```

or

```
script arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 - 10
```

You may be able to make the code look like this:

```
 eval '(('jd2=${jd1}+${5}'))' jd2date $jd2
```

The command would be called like so:

```
script arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 10
```

`${5}`, `${6}`, `${jd1}`, and `$jd2` are substituted with the contents of their
respective variables. Variables that are numbers (e.g. `$5` and `$6`) are [positional
parameters](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0130.php).

Since you no longer need the operator to be placed by a variable, the call to
`eval` is not necessary. Your code may look like this:

```
 (( jd2=${jd1}+${5} ))
 jd2date $jd2
```

Or, with slightly cleaner syntax:

```
 (( jd2 = jd1 + $5 ))
 jd2date $jd2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the code fragment, but here's an example of the use of eval along with a comparison with similar command substitution operators:

```
$ echo `echo 2 + 2 | bc`
4
$ echo $(echo 2 + 2 | bc)
4
$ eval "echo 2 + 2 | bc"
4
$ echo "date"
date
$ eval "date"
Thu Oct 10 21:20:01 EDT 2013
```

So eval "evaluates" a command, or series of commands, and returns the result of running that command. For the life of me, I can't figure out any use for `eval` beyond that which can be done by either running the commands directly or using the backquote or `$(...)` syntax.